# Setting up VNC via Putty Ubuntu 10.4.2 LTS

Tags: vnc

I have just setup my server with ubuntu desktop, after running the sudo apt-get install-desktop, and rebooting I now want to login to the dektop remotely, from my Windows PC. 
How do I enable remote VNC / Teamviewer access via the SSH command line?

Comment: do you have autologin setup there as well or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternate would be to use FreeNX . Freenx is secure and faster then VNC.

See [The Ubuntu Wiki FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) page.

If you want to tunnel VNC over SSH I personally would use an alternate VNC server, vnc4server.

You would then ssh in with putty, tunnel the VNC port over SSH, start the vncserver, and then connect with a vnx client.

It might sound complex, but there is a very nice walk through here:

[Tunnelling VNC over SSH with PuTTY](http://martybugs.net/smoothwall/puttyvnc.cgi)

It is a graphical guide (best one I know) doing exactly what you want.

The advantage of tunneling over ssh is the it increases security.

I would also advise you use keys and disable password authentication.

[Ubuntu wiki ssh keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)

And finally, here is a walk through on how to import open-ssh keys to putty

[Putty import ssh keys](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-rsa-dsa-keys/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin vnc server vino, however to configure it remotely without a gui is painfull. The easiest it to run `ssh vino-preferences` from a linux LiveCD. You can use `vino-passwd` to set the password.

Alternative is to install `x11vnc` (from x11vnc package). No need gui to configure. Just install and run it from the putty window.

If you are not logged as a user on that ubuntu box, then you will need to do some tricks with X cookie permissions. It is described in error message from the `x11vnc` command (just the file path is bit different in Ubuntu). Sorry, I don't remember the details, but it wasn't difficult.

It is better (safer) to start vnc server only on 127.0.0.1 and tunnel it over secure SSH tunnel (there are options for that in putty).

Good luck.